# Is it possible to combine a stream with no parameters with standard linked streams when declaring a HoloViews DynamicMap?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

What I'm trying to do is make an interactive scatter plot where I can control which columns of a DataFrame are on X and Y axes and then select a subset of data using lasso or something similar. Because of the dataset size I have to use datashader.

I tried to declare the DynamicMap as:

```
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(selector.make_view, kdims=[], streams=[selector, RangeX(), RangeY(), Stream.define('Next')()])
```

and have a custom callback on the lasso which would select desired rows of data, create the visual representation and update the plot with `dmap.event()`.

So that doesn't seem to work. If I select something, the plot gets updated only when I pan or zoom or change axes selection. [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16VAmkD2VqsDa3j1P7DdBfR_4-EgByFZ0/view?usp=sharing)

If I leave only `Stream.define('Next')()`:

```
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(selector.make_view, kdims=[], streams=[Stream.define('Next')()])
```

then lasso updates the plot, but I loose everything else including the ability to zoom. [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uDEugGOviXTFe-Pq10rLAVZ8AdtpW_IF/view?usp=sharing)

I hope this question makes sense. If needed, I've pushed the notebook [here](https://github.com/markozecevic/nbgate/blob/master/nbgate.ipynb).